# Running arbitrary commands in mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I've got some protocol buffers definitions, in `proto/*.proto`. My current Makefile-based build system compiles each of them into an Erlang module and header, and into a self-descriptor (as a `.pb` file) and then embeds the descriptor as a BEAM module:

```
foo.proto -> foo_pb.erl, foo_pb.hrl
          -> foo.pb -> foo_pb_desc.beam
```

I've implemented a `mix_protobuffs` task to do the first step, and the `foo.proto -> foo.pb` part-step.

I've also got the relevant code for embedding an arbitrary file into an Erlang module -- inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2160696) -- but I'm wondering about the recommended way of integrating it into my mix-based build process.

Similarly, I've got some other files that need to be processed and then embedded, which suggests that I shouldn't make the `mix_protobuffs` task know about embedding.

So I guess I'm asking: **is there a way to have mix run arbitrary commands pre/post another task?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way would be to define your own compiler. For that, you are to create a module in `Mix.Task.Compiler` namespace *and* implement [`Mix.Task.Compiler`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.Compiler.html#content) behaviour. Also the `project/0` function of your `mix.exs` should be updated to return your new compiler. Somewhat like below would do.

```rb
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protobufs do
  use Mix.Task.Compiler

  @recursive true

  @impl Mix.Task.Compiler
  def run(argv) do
    # do your compilation, possibly with System.cmd/3
    :ok
  end
end
```

And in your project file:

```rb
def project do
  [
    compilers: Mix.compilers() ++ [:protobufs],
    # ...
  ]
end
```

You also can call any existing `mix` task from your own task, like `Mix.Tasks.Run.run(args)`.

Comment: I already implemented a `Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protobuff`; it was the second (common) part that I was interested in.

In the end, I implemented `Mix.Tasks.Compile.Embed` and made it read wildcards from `project()[:embed]`, then put it in the appropriate place in the `compilers()` list.